# Cannot resolve method 'getResult' in 'QuerySnapshot'

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

How to solve this? the getResult() is error. In fact, all my implementations in build.gradle are latest version.

[image: Error]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 0):

The `onSuccess` method gets a [`QuerySnapshot` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) as its argument, which indeed does not have a `getResult()` method.

Are you looking for [`querySnapshot.getDocuments()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#getDocuments()) or [`querySnapshot.iterator()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#public-iteratorquerydocumentsnapshot-iterator) by any chance?

I highly recommend keeping the reference docs I linked handy while coding, as I find they are the fastest way to fix issues such as this.